# pandas sum of group of elements with certain relative difference

Tags: python, pandas

```
time  | value
1         4
2         5
20        7
------------
50        8
55        10
74        12
------------
100       1
105       21
120       0
```

How to get the sum of values for each group of elements: such that the group has relative difference between each element and the next that is less than 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe need [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) with [`ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ge.html) for `>=20` and [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for `Series` as argument for `groupby` and aggregate `sum`:

```
df = df.groupby(df['time'].diff().ge(20).cumsum())['value'].sum()
print (df)
time
0    16
1    30
2    22
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['time'].diff().ge(20).cumsum())
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    2
7    2
8    2
Name: time, dtype: int32
```